# Upload file to server in Windows mobile C# project

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, upload

We have a setup of server and windows mobile device as a client. In server CSI script ready to accept single file from client.

In Desktop we have use WebClient.UploadFile method to upload file to server, but in windows mobile this isn't implemented, till now we haven't found any alternative method to achieve same.

Thanks in advance.
Ramanand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the .NET Compact Framework, you can use [`System.Net.HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) instead of `WebClient`, which isn't supported on .NET CF.

Since `WebClient` is implemented on top of `HttpWebRequest`, you can do everything with `HttpWebRequest` that you can with `WebClient`, albeit with more code.

For example, to download the contents of a URL into a string, you can use this code:

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url); 
    string html; 
    using (var r = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()) 
    { 
        using(var r2 = (TextReader)new StreamReader(r)) 
        { 
            html = r2.ReadToEnd(); 
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the method in this post, you could maybe do some refactoring to fit your purpose better.
[Upload files with HTTPWebrequest (multipart/form-data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data/567460#567460)