# Upload files with HTTPWebrequest (multipart/form-data) for Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

Want to do similar as link below but in Windows Mobile ..

[Upload files with HTTPWebrequest (multipart/form-data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data)

Can any one help???

Content from the link above:

Is there any class, library or some piece of code which will help me to upload files with HTTPWebrequest?

Edit 2:

I do not want to upload to a WebDAV folder or something like that. I want to simulate a browser, so just like you upload your avatar to a forum or upload a file via form in a web application. Upload to a form which uses a multipart/form-data.

Edit:

WebClient is not cover my requirements, so I'm looking for a solution with HTTPWebrequest.

Comment: so, you want us to rewrite this code for you?

Comment: Not rewrite but am new to windows phone application development and i want to do almost similar thing in windows phone so i just want guidance ... don't know how i can send image via httpwebrequest as there is not such feature in Windows mobile :(

Comment: So is this for Windows Phone or Windows Mobile?  There is a distict difference.

Answer (score 0):

Windows mobile also supports HttpWebRequest class and you can create http POST/PUT request to upload a file to a server. 
Check this post: [Upload file to server in Windows mobile C# project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740375/upload-file-to-server-in-windows-mobile-c-project)